# creating bar chart for a month but only showing data from 13:00:00 to 17:00:00 elasticsearch kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I am using elasticsearch version 7.1 in AWS.

I've created a bar chart where x-axis is using date histogram aggregation in 4h interval.
Below is my bar chart, sorry for inputting picture but I've figured it is best way to represent what I have and what I want to do.

[image]

Each bar takes 4hour interval worth of data and adds it up from given period Jan-31 to Feb-02. For given interval I would like to show bars for only 13:00:00 ~ 17:00:00 therefore I have one bar for each day.

So from Jan-31 ~ Feb-02 I would have one bar for Jan-31 13:00:00 ~17:00:00, 2nd bar for Feb-01 13:00:00 ~ 17:00:00 and 3rd bar for Feb-02 13:00:00 ~17:00:00.

I found that I could use scripted field and add extra column called hour of day as said here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-filter-for-a-specific-time-range/105169/2 I have huge data so do not want to use scripted field.

Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.